# Php captcha returns old captcha value

Tags: javascript, php, session, captcha

I am following [this](http://www.ivebe.com/blog/simple-php-captcha-tutorial.html) captcha tutorial with a partial success, actually I managed to make it work but now I need to validate the form by Javascript, in order to to that I have the following PHP script.

```
<? session_start(); ?>

<html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php                                                                                                                                
  echo "\n<script type=\"text/javascript\">";                                                                            
  echo "\n\tfunction validateCaptcha(captcha){ ";
  echo "\n\t alert(captcha); }";
  echo "\n</script>";                                                                                                                  
?>                                                                                                                                   

<form action=next.php method=get onsubmit="return validateCaptcha('<?php 
  $catp = $_SESSION['captcha'];
  echo $catp;
?>')"/>
  <img src="captcha.php" /><br />
  <input type="text" name="answer" placeholder="Enter captcha here" />
  <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that each time I press on the button Send the form is not validated because the captcha value is the old one, I've been struggling with it a couple of hours I could not figure out how to make it work. For me it is weird because the Javascript code generated has the good value.

I also tried using hidden variables such as:

```
    <input id="checkCaptcha" name="checkCaptcha" type="hidden" value="<?php 
      $catp = $_SESSION['captcha']; echo $catp; ?>" />
```

but I did not succeed.

By the way this is the captcha.php code:

```
<?php

session_start();

header("Expires: Tue, 01 Jan 2013 00:00:00 GMT"); 
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT"); 
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

$chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$randomString = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) 
{
    $randomString .= $chars[rand(0, strlen($chars)-1)];
}

$_SESSION['captcha'] = strtolower( $randomString );

$im = @imagecreatefrompng("captcha_bg.png"); 

imagettftext($im, 30, 0, 10, 38, imagecolorallocate ($im, 0, 0, 0), 'larabiefont.ttf', $randomString);

header ('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im, NULL, 0);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

I know I could use [reCaptcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/) but I would prefer solve it before.

Comment: if you are sending captcha in session to your browser then why you are using it as the purpose of security fails.

Comment: It is supposed to work as a barrier for machine submission in a bug report form. The idea is to validate the captcha before sending the email to the development team.

Comment: Don't forget the quotes in `next.php` and `get`:  `action="next.php" method="get"`

Comment: you should check empty validation for captcha at javascript end and valid captcha entry with session entry in php side.

Comment: Thanks! actually I did already in next.php but I was wondering if there existed a way to do the validation by Javascript, but if the best way to do it is in next.php I am going to do so.